# Algorithmic Puzzle

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

How to distribute 1000$ in ten boxes so that any amount of money between $1 and $1000(both inclusive) can be given as some combinations of these boxes.

Please provide any hints on how to approach this.I tried but couldn't make any solution.

Comment: big hint: powers of 2

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not programming related.

Comment: @Lior Kogan:so can you provide any links where i can post such questions??

Comment: This is a puzzle rather a typical brain teaser where in little bit of computer fundamental(Base 2 conversion) would make you come to the solution.

Comment: @user122345656: Please provide a clear question, as it is the question  is very confusing.What does combinations mean?

Comment: @Jason: the largest can be 489

Comment: @Aravind: Combination means does any boxes exists that sum up to a given amount.
Say one want $3 so  combination of boxes  whose amount sum to $3(like :$1 and $2) will work.

Comment: @Jason:Yes amount is $1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write all the numbers from 1 to 1000 in base-two representation. These numbers require ten bits since `2^10 = 1024`. Your boxes are powers of two up to `2^8`, and `489` for the last box (`2^0` to `2^8` and `489` gives you ten boxes and `2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^8 + 489 = 2^9 - 1 + 489 = 511 + 489 = 1000`), and the bit representations give you proof that you can write any number of to 1000 as a combination of these boxes (clearly anything up to 511 is okay, for anything greater than 511, subtract 489 and then note that you can write the remainder as a combination of the other 8 boxes since it is guaranteed to be less than or equal to 511).

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will work on this.

Answer (score 3):

have you ever did binary to decimal conversion ? Take any number between 1 and 1000 and try converting it into binary. You'll figure out that you are dealing in powers of 2.

Distribute in powers of 2 and then for whatever amount you need, just convert it into binary and pick those boxes for which bit is set to 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "you are dealing in powers of 2"?Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: How do you convert a decimal into binary? You have a kind of GP series with common ratio = 2. Like if you need to convert  15(let say the amount) then you will have :  **.....,16, 8, 4, 2, 1 ** something of this sort and for 15, you need  last four numbers (8+4+2+1) means these bits are set to 1 gives you 1111 as 15. Now, in terms of puzzle, put the amount in boxes in forms of powers of 2 and then for 15, convert it to binary, find the set bit, and pick boxes for those numbers.

Comment: Thanx for your ans i got the logic.

Comment: @VaibhavShukla: Thanks, I din't understand the question, once the question was clear, everything fell in place!